# How to open a badly formatted csv using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have a 27513 line CSV file that sometimes has a comma where it shouldn't.

If I open the file in Excel by double clicking the csv file in Windows Explorer, Excel manages to format it properly, even if some cells here and there have a comma amongst their text.

If I use typical VBA code to import the csv file, those errors are not fixed.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private uri As String
Private ws As Worksheet

Private Sub btnUpload_Click()

    shtRawData.Activate
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RawData") 'set to current worksheet name
    
    uri = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv),*.csv", , "Please select text file...")
    
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & uri, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
         .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
         .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
         .Refresh
    End With
 
End Sub
```

I understand that the code above is not broken.
I understand as well that the csv is badly formatted and should use a different delimiter, be it a double quote, tab, or happy face emoji.

There's simply something more that Excel does when you double click on a csv file and it opens it up.

What is it that Excel does to guess correctly (at least, in this case) the correct format of the file, and how can VBA do the same?

Comment: Maybe look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.textfiletextqualifier  If a CSV contains a field which itself contains a comma, that field should be surrounded by `""`, so you need to configure that setting for the import.  Seems that happens by default when opening by double-clicking the file.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was simply to use `workbooks.open`.
Whatever magic excel does is captured in this function.